# Blank div is taking &nbsp in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, html

I've created a custom page in magento 1.9 and there I am using a blank div

```
 <div class="clearfix"></div>
```

when I'm refreshing my page it's taking &nbsp like

```
 <div class="clearfix">&nbsp;</div>
```

Someone would tell me why is this happening.

Comment: which editor are you using ? Its possible the editor not the browser. So when you save the file it automatically fills the blank div with `&nbsp;`

Comment: I'm using sublime but when I paste the code on magento server it did not take at that time but as I save that page it takes &nbsp;

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's by default feature.

If you are working on CI, or some other framework, or simple Html it will

not print &nbsp

But when you open your magento folder in Sublime it adds &nbsp

You can check with other text editors also, and let me know your feedback

Comment: It's not printing anything except space. It looks like that I've given line height to those elements. Is there anyway to remove that?